# Include installers as part of C++ utility in visual studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-6

I am developing a Windows C++ utility using MFC Framework in Visual Studio 6.0(Need to have this combination because of some internal requirements).

My utility installs some softwares, and then configure them from registry. Hence I need to bundle the dependent installer files along with my executable. How can I bundle them all together, so that we can provide an executable to our users which will include all required installer files along with the utility.

PS: I am new to Visual Studio Development environment.

Comment: [Introduction to Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468900.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create an installer use something like [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create a single EXE that can deploy multiple files.